# Scala Future: Transform Future[Vector[T]] to Future[Result]

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I have a method that creates a `Future` of type `Vector` from which I then want to create an appropriate HTTP response.

I have tried to implement this so far using the `transform` and `transformWith` methods from the Futures API mostly because they have the `Try[T]` signature for their arguments and I can distinguish between success and failure.

Let's assume that this is the method producing the `Future` of type `Vector`

```scala
def aCoupleOfFutures: Future[Vector[String]] = ???
```

Using this approach one can notice the repetitive use of `Try` structure

```scala
val foo:Future[Result] = aCoupleOfFutures.transform {
    case Success(strings) => Try(Created(json.Json.toJson(strings)))
    case Failure(e) => Try(BadRequest(e.getMessage))
}
```

Using this approach one can notice the repetitive use of `Future.successful` nesting.

```scala
val foo:Future[Result] = aCoupleOfFutures.transformWith {
    case Success(strings) => Future.successful(Created(json.Json.toJson(strings)))
    case Failure(e) => Future.successful(BadRequest(e.getMessage))
}
```

Using this approach I cannot return the needed `BadRequest` when there's an exception produced from the service. Since the signature of the overloaded `transform` method is (`def transform[S](s: T => S, f: Throwable => Throwable)`)

```scala
val foo:Future[Result] = aCoupleOfFutures.transform (
    options => Created(json.Json.toJson(options)),
    exc => exc
)
```

So my question is: Can I have something like the following:

```scala
val result:Future[Result] = aCoupleOfFutures. someKindOfTransform {
    case Success(options) => Created(json.Json.toJson(options))
    case Failure(e) => BadRequest(e.getMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option seems to be splitting it up into `map` and `recover` steps:

```
val result = aCoupleOfFutures
  .map(options => Created(json.Json.toJson(options)))
  .recover{ case exc => BadRequest(exc.getMessage)}
```

You're right that there doesn't seem to be a single transformation method doing what you want - the closest signaturewise seems to be `onComplete`, but that returns `Unit` and so doesn't allow you to produce a return value. That said, separating the two isn't necessarily a bad thing, as you'll often want to abstract out the error-handling logic across all your controllers.

Comment: This does seem to work with the only correction that recover receives a partial function and `recover(exc => BadRequest(exc.getMessage))` does not seem to be valid but `.recover{case e:Throwable => BadRequest(e.getMessage)}` is.

Comment: You're right, oversight on my part! It's now been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The fold operation will be useful here-

```
def fold[U](fa: Throwable => U, fb: T => U): U
```

It's a terminal operation, you want to convert all result or exceptions to `Result`. A fold operation over a try/either/option transforms the entire thing in whichever state to a type `U`.

```
val result = aCoupleOfFutures
  .transform(
    tryResult =>
      Success(
        tryResult.fold(th => BadRequest(th.getMessage), options => Created(json.Json.toJson(options)))
      )
  )
```